# How do I make a slider in HTML that fill itself in behind with a gradient

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, gradient

I'm just playing around in HTML and I wanted to make a slider that fills itself in with a gradient, and I found this close to being impossible. I have been researching for hours and I can't seem to find an answer.

I assume I need JS for this but I am completely blank there.

```css
.slidecontainer {
  justify-content: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.8;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
```

I have tried exactly what I said above. I have been trying things from this website (https://codepen.io/kaiquenunes23/pen/LYEvegK) but I can't put my finger around it.

I have also read multiple other threads on StackOverflow.

Comment: use jquery ui slider or some plugin,

Comment: Maybe this could help cause it seems to be working really well: https://medium.com/@manoj10101996/customize-your-input-range-slider-into-gradient-slider-without-any-external-stylesheet-be8d6ec224ce

Comment: @Korovjov Its not exactly what I am looking for but almost. Everything in front of the slider is supposed to be a different color, like "#d3d3d3". And everything behind is supposed to be a gradient. Image like a "movable progress bar"

Comment: Do you want the gradient image to look as though it is gradually being uncovered or do you want it to all be there and just expand as the slider is moved to the right?

Comment: @AHaworth The first option. I want the slider to uncover the gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need JS to get the current position of the thumb.

This snippet does this by reading the positions on the slider and calculating the percentage it has been moved. It then sets a CSS variable --pc to that percentage value.

The slider is given two background images, first is one that is transparent up to the thumb and then is the gray color you want.  And 'underneath it' is the second background image which is whatever linear gradient you want.

In this way the linear-gradient is revealed as you move the slider to the right.

```js
const slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
slider.addEventListener("input", update);

function update() {
  const pc = (slider.value - slider.min) / (slider.max - slider.min) * 100 + '%';
  slider.style.setProperty('--pc', pc);
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  justify-content: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  --pc: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0 var(--pc), #d3d3d3 var(--pc) 100%), linear-gradient(to right, red, green);
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.8;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
```

Comment: This worked in the snippet but didnt work in my files. I get no error messeges but it doesn't work. I am currently on chrome version 110.0.5481.178. 
Any idea why?

Comment: If you want my HTML, CSS and JS files please tell me.

Comment: I don't think it will be the version of Chrome that you are using that is the problem - more likely some other CSS that your site is using. Have you used your browsers dev tools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied to the slider?

Comment: I dont find anything weird there.
Can it have to do with that I am viewing the website from my file path?
I just paste "file:///C:/Users/nemo02/Documents/HTML,CSS,JS/index.html" into Google.

Comment: That's a very weird file path. Are you on Windows? I don't understand the HTML,CSS,JS part. What is your folder structure?

Comment: Yes I am on Windows. The "HTML,CSS,JS" is just what I call the folder where I keep the html, css, js, icon, image, and sound files. I get that file path if i select copy path in VS Code. It's the same as "C:\Users\nemo02\Documents\HTML,CSS,JS\index.html\"

Comment: so what is in index.html?

Comment: That is the html file. I select where I wanna be "HTML,CSS,JS" and then what I want to open "index.html".
I currently dont have a web server so this works for now

Comment: The code worked on JSFiddle so I assume it has to do with how I veiw my website. I'll get back once I set up my web server.
Thnkas!

Comment: I have no problem running it from my WIndows filestore.

Comment: Weird. Well it works everywhere else but my computer so the code obviously works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
```

Comment: Still dosen't work